# Android emulator sometimes does not connect to the internet

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have ubuntu Linux 10.04, my collegue uses suse. We have Wi-Fi connection to the Internet. We use Android emulator with several virtual devices. We have problem with the Internet connection of the virtual devices. Normally it works well but sometimes (about 25%) the virtual device shows no GSM signal and no Internet even if the PC is connected. There is no clear reason of that behaviour. It will stay disconnected forever so if it happens, we will have to restart the virtual device and hope that the next attempt will be OK. It happens sometimes to all Android version virtual device but it is more common on Android 2.x than Android 1.x. Does anybody have the same error?

Comment: I use windows and I have the same problem sometimes. I don't know a solution, restarting emulator solves it for me.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't disable the internet access by accident by clicking F8 ?

Comment: I use Mac OS X and have the same problem.  It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the new snapshot feature to save a good snapshot to restore from with the network up. I've done this with my CI build and it appears to have solved the problem.

Comment: This has the added benefit of dramatically improving load times for the AVD.  See http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2011/03/tip-speeding-up-your-android-emulator.html for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error on Windows. What **seems** to work for me is is treating the VD like a real phone and turning it off before shutting the window - so press and hold the power button, then selecting power off from the popup dialog then give it a short while to shutdown *(if you watch from the DDMS logcat view in Eclipse you can see it running through the shutdown processes)*. It won't actually close the window, but you will see the logcat activity basically stop. Then close the window.

I find if I close the VD like this, I don't get any problems when I next come to start the VD, but if I don't maybe even 1 in 3 times it won't start properly the next time.