# Android Emulator occasionally fails to start network

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, gsm, android-virtual-device

Every few times I open the emulator, it will appear to be in offline mode, with the "X" on the top of screen instead of the 3g symbol and no apparent network connectivity.

The only apparent difference in the logs I've found is:

```
Network works:
12-03 11:24:48.732 D/qemud   (   37): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'gsm'
12-03 11:24:48.732 D/qemud   (   37): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 2
12-03 11:24:48.742 D/qemud   (   37): client_registration: registration succeeded for client 2

Network fails:
12-03 03:02:11.688 D/qemud   (   37): client_fd_receive: attempting registration for service 'gsm'
12-03 03:02:11.688 D/qemud   (   37): client_fd_receive:    -> received channel id 2
```

Does anybody have an idea why the registration would not succeed from one run to another?

Comment: See similar question here: still no answers to the problem, but to save reposting as an asnwer I'll leave it as a comment: [Android emulator sometimes does not connect to the internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336297/android-emulator-sometimes-does-not-connect-to-the-internet/4336694#4336694)

Comment: Observed the same behaviour in the past. One suggestion: when starting VD give it time, so do not start any application until Android loads all system services. Since I follow this simple rule, it does not happen often to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is for CI, a temporary workaround was needed. Our build first runs a gating test to check that the network came up without issue. Each time our tests kick off, the emulator is created and tested for network connectivity. Only if the network is up do the tests run, otherwise rescheduling for a few minutes later (with  a new emulator instance). While this doesn't prevent the problem, it does prevent our continuous integration system from producing false failures.

The way I am testing for if the network is up is with a small groovy script that runs as a separate job:

```
String status=
   ['sh', '-c', 'adb shell dumpstate | grep -m1 \"Mobile data state: \"'].execute().text.trim();

if (status=="Mobile data state: CONNECTED") {
   System.exit(0);
} else {
   System.exit(1);
}
```

While potentially wasteful of resources, it beats the alternative of intermittent failure emails.